# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Hi guys I'm having an error when I'm trying to run the training using this command:

```
> `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/
> --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config`
```

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "train.py", line 51, in
>   <module> from object_detection.builders import model_builder File
>   "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py",
>   line 35, in <module> from object_detection.models import
>   faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
>   File
>   "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\models                                          \faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py",
>   line 28, in <module> from nets import inception_resnet_v2
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get the most out of your question, it would be helpful if your example was [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and there was sufficient information for another user to recreate your error.

Answer (score 0):

The `nets` module is in `slim` folder, you need to add the `slim` library to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Comment: thank you but slim library is already added to the PYTHONPATH

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1842 This could probably help

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing pip install nets and also check the site package and environment package for installed folders (It worked for me)